# Call method "in parent" from instance

Tags: objective-c, class

I have a class that connects via Bluetooth to a device and this returns me values ​​when the device generates this values, I'm instantiating this class from a "main class", but I need that when the dipositive return a value, the instance who get the values, call a method in the "main class"

Comment: This would be much easier with a small code sample of what calls what and what code you want to run.

Comment: Do you mean simply doing `super ->someMethod()`?

Comment: in ObjC syntax `[super someMethod]`

Comment: super is a reference for UIViewController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need that when the dipositive return a value, the instance who get the values, call a method in the "main class"

The only way one object (the caller) can send a message to another (the callee) is if the caller has (or can get) a reference to the callee. So... when your "main" object creates the device-connecting object, have the main object give the device-connecting object a pointer to itself.

You've essentially described a delegation relationship, where the device-connecting object is the delegator and the main object is the delegate.